# MVC3 and KnockoutJS DRYly

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js, dry

So the way I've always worked with MVC in .Net is to create ViewModels for each View.

Now, with using Knockout, would I create my ViewModels in javascript instead of a C# class? And then have my main Model(in this case, EF generated Models) as my only C# Model classes?  Or would I still go about create a C# ViewModel class along with my Knockout ViewModel?

I'm trying to set this project up DRYly, but I'm not sure of best practices in this situation.

Answer (score 2):

You can create viewmodels (VMs) for the C# server side and still have them intended for the ASP.NET MVC Views. Then create VMs for the client side javascript views too. But the way I;ve liked it best is to use the MVC Views as the basis for the page, and have the Models be the basis for the JavaScript models. The only VM would then be the JavaScript VM since most of the presentation is really done client side. In other words, do the more static plumbing in MVC, then do the dynamic interaction client side.

If you are building primarily  using client side JS libraries like KO I would not start with a VM for the MVC side unless you have a strong reason for it.

If you have specific questions, I'd be happy to try to help.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create view models as you always do.
2. Create a HTML helper which generates a KO view model from it.

Answer (score 0):

You should base your Knockout viewmodel on the view data from the server in order to at least have it initialized with data from the server without having to make a separate request to get that data.

You can optionally use the [mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) to map the view data to your viewmodel.